# QTP 10 with IE8 (Descriptive method)

Tags: qtp, hp-uft, qtpositioning

I'm New to QTP 10. I am having a couple of issues when using descriptive programming,

1. In some screens, while performing a click event

   1. Screen sizes get shrinked eg: `iframe` `body`
   2. Some times a Menu Panel is disappearing
2. We are trying to automate a big application and it has number of Save buttons (And other buttons) which are using with the same object properties. On that time we failed to get a unique property value, So We were using `abs_x`, `abs_y` , `x`, `y` values. These coordinate values are changing from system to system and in fact it has changed a number of times in same system itself.

How to resolve these problem?

Comment: Also to add to an answer by Motti, UFT also supports [**`xpath`**](https://www.google.com/search?q=uft+xpath+descriptive+programming&oq=UFT+xpath&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l4.7368j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) property which will help identifying objects uniquely.

Answer (score 2):

You really shouldn't be using QTP10 in 2016. QTP's name was changed to UFT and the current version is 12.54. The license for QTP is also valid for UFT so I don't see why not to upgrade.

In any case you should **not** use `abs_x` and `abs_y` in description, this is very brittle and can change between test runs. You should try to find a way to identify your objects in a way that is intrinsic to the object.

By upgrading to UFT you'll get some more functionality (for example [Insight - Image Based Testing](https://community.hpe.com/t5/All-About-the-Apps/A-guide-to-Image-Based-Testing-with-HP-UFT-s-Insight/ba-p/6355855)) which may solve your identification issues. Another option is to ask your R&D team to add some properties to the HTML to help testing.